# Count JQuery values twig

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I try to display the number of elements of my twig table in JQuery but the result shows me 0 whereas I have 2 results.

My Twig

```
<tr class="info">
                                                <td>
                                                    {{ r.residence[key].name }}<br/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="name-count-resid">{{ r.name }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ r.prenom }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ r.email }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ r.tel }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ r.port }}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {% for key in r.groups|keys %}
                                                        {{ r.groups[key].name }}<br/>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
```

My script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var n = 0;
        $('name-count-resid').each(function () {
            var name = $(this);
            var count = name.closest('tr').find('name-count-resid');
            n += (name.html() * count.val());
        });
        alert(n);
        $('#nb-member-selected').append("Nbr: " + n);
    });
</script>
```

thank you.

Comment: ID's have to be unique, switch up to class

Comment: Result "NaN" with class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not even sure what you are trying to do with that code. If `r` is an element of the collection or an array `registrants` you can do this in twig by :

```
<table>
    {% for r in registrants %}
    <tr class="info">
        <td>
            {{ r.residence[key].name }}<br/>
        </td>
        <td class="name-count-resid">{{ r.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.prenom }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.tel }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.port }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for key in r.groups|keys %}
                {{ r.groups[key].name }}<br/>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr class="total">
        <td colspan="7">{{ registrants | length }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or if you really want to use jquery you just have to do this

```js
$(function() {
  $('.total td').html($('.name-count-resid').length);
});
```

```css
table td {
  border : 1px solid #A2A2A2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 {% for r in registrants %}
 <tr class="info">
  <td>
   {{ r.residence[key].name }}<br/>
  </td>
  <td class="name-count-resid">{{ r.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ r.prenom }}</td>
  <td>{{ r.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ r.tel }}</td>
  <td>{{ r.port }}</td>
  <td>
   {% for key in r.groups|keys %}
    {{ r.groups[key].name }}<br/>
   {% endfor %}
  </td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 <tr class="total">
  <td colspan="7">0</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use # to find something by it's id

```
var count = name.closest('tr').find('#name-count-resid');
```

you must use "#" for ids, "." for classes and nothing, for elements (like, tr, a, body, p, strong, table, etc).

Comment: The same result, I had to try :)